# Select Distinct Years and Months for Django Archive Page

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-views, django-queryset

I want to make an archive_index page for my django site. However, the date-based generic views really aren't any help. I want the dictionary returned by the view to have all the years and months for which at least one instance of the object type exists. So if my blog started in September 2007, but there were no posts in April 2008, I could get something like this

```
2009 - Jan, Feb, Mar
2008 - Jan, Feb, Mar, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec
2007 - Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This will give you a list of unique posting dates:

```
Posts.objects.filter(draft=False).dates('post_date','month',order='DESC')
```

Of course you might not need the draft filter, and change 'post_date' to your field name, etc.

Comment: For anyone who has a `DateTimeField` it's simply `.datetimes(...)`.

Comment: in case of dates ?

Comment: This answer works perfectly for me, I used something like `.distinct('post_date')` didn't work

Answer (score 14):

I found the answer to my own question.

[It's on this page](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/) in the documentation.

There's a function called dates that will give you distinct dates. So I can do

Entry.objects.dates('pub_date','month') to get a list of datetime objects, one for each year/month.

Comment: That's funny you can answer your own question.  I would add your findings to your original post though, too.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get all the info you describe from the built-in views. Can you be more specific as to what you cannot get? This should have everything you need:

```
django.views.generic.date_based.archive_month
```

[Reference page](http://docs.djangobrasil.org/ref/generic-views.html) (search for the above string on that page)

Comment: No, that gives the actual objects for the month. I don't want the objects. I just want the distinct months and years themselves.